# Flutter: Constraints not constraining widget (explanation needed)

Tags: dart, flutter

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UnconstrainedBox(
        child: Container(
            height: 250.0,
            width: 250.0,
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
            child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.5,
                child: Container( // WIDGET IN QUESTION
                    constraints:
                        BoxConstraints.expand(width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                    color: Colors.yellow))));
  }
}
```

**According to the [Container class documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)...**

*If the widget has no child and no alignment, but a height, width, or constraints are provided, then the Container tries to be as small as possible given the combination of those constraints and the parent's constraints.*

Instead, the widget is trying to be as large as possible (size of parent) rather than 50x50. I understand that I can use something like `UnconstrainedBox`, but I'm looking for an explanation of this behavior.

**Looking for:**
[image: looking-for]

**Currently getting:**
[image: currently-getting]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is your root Container.

By setting a width+height *without* an `alignment`, Container forces its child to fill the available space.

If you want that child take the least amount of space, you need to specify your root container how it should align its child within its bounds.

```
Container(
  width: 250,
  height: 250,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Whatever(),
);
```

Comment: This is super helpful! Is there a good place where I can read up on this / build an intuition around it?

Comment: In container.dart, I see the following

    if (alignment != null)
      current = new Align(alignment: alignment, child: current);

But it's not clear to me that the Align widget is needed for children to be sized correctly in this case.

Comment: Just bear in mind that widgets don't magically align their child within their bounds.

Comment: If you have a Parent that ask for a 250x250 and its child wants 50x50, then constraints are incompatible. Flutter won't try to guess what you wanted to do. It will fulfill the parent constraint instead.

Comment: Isn't the parent just saying that it wants to be 250x250? If that's the case, there is plenty of room for a child that wants to be 50x50 with a default origin of 0,0. Yeah?

Comment: Overall, it seems that size and alignment should not be interdependent in this case.

Comment: A parent gives a child constraints ((max/min)(Width/Height)) and the child decides what size it wants to be.

Comment: This would require more code overall. You'd have to wrap most tons of stuff inside a `SizedBox.expand` or similar. And computing the desired minimal size of an object requires more CPU than simply filling it's parent

Comment: Not sure how much overhead it would be, but I just want it to be deterministic. For the most part, if you stay away from Container, you stay away from the complexity of it's build function (many conditional return values).

Also, I just inspected the constraints being passing from the parent to the child using LayoutBuilder and figured out that without alignment, the ((max/min)(Width/Height)) are actually tight...aka the parent is telling the child exactly what height it can be. Thanks so much for your responsive help!

Comment: The overhead is pretty big. By filling its parent, the size computation is as simple as `BoxConstraints.biggest`. While to compute the smalest size, you'd have to compute the size/location of each and every element of your descendants (which may have to do the same).

Comment: Very helpful article "flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know" https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2