# Flutter sizing of constrained box to its maxHeight resp. minHeight

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ConstrainedBox with minHeight 50 and maxHeight 400. The CB contains a Container that colors itself yellow.

Note that CB here serves as an abstraction. Basically, that CB might be any kind of widget that has min/max constraints.

Now I have two scenarios:

- I want to make the CB as big as possible (take maxHeight).
- I want to make the CB as small as possible (take minHeight).

I tried

```
Widget build(BuildContext _) => Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SizedBox.expand(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 400),
              child: Container(color: Colors.yellow))));
```

which shows a fullscreen yellow box, but I want 400 pixels!

```
  Widget build(BuildContext _) => Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SizedBox.shrink(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 400),
              child: Container(color: Colors.yellow))));
```

which results in an empty Scaffold, but I want 50 pixels!

EDIT: I solved the problem, please see my own answer.

Comment: case one: `ConstrainedBox > SizedBox.expand > Container`, case two: `ConstrainedBox > SizedBox.shrink > Container` - the opposite for `SizedBox.expand` is `SizedBox.shrink`

Comment: btw you can do that with `Container > SizedBox.expand` and `Container > SizedBox.shrink` too - no need for top `ConstrainedBox`

Comment: so, the question is: do you need that `ConstrainedBox` at all? cannot you just use `Container > SizedBox.expand` / `Container > SizedBox.shrink`?

Comment: @pskink the point is that I have a widget CB that has some inherent constraints, which I don’t know.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/244qAL but you can do the same with `ConstrainedBox > SizedBox.[expand|shrink] > Container` widget hierarchy

Comment: @pskink That CB Widget is given to me as a Blackbox. I don’t know what’s inside. I only know that it has some minimum and maximum height. Probably I am misunderstanding Flutter’s constraint propagation???

Comment: So is there no way to ask a Widget to lay itself out as small resp. as big as possible?

Comment: i dont understand how you can have it as a blackbox if you explicitly write `ConstrainedBox` in your code (i mean it is not passed like: `child: myConstrainedBoxWhichIGotFromSomewhere`)

Comment: @pskink that was an example for the purpose of explaining the problem I need to solve.

Comment: @pskink am I now correctly understanding that constraints are always enforced top down and there is now way for a widget to advertise to its parent that it can be laid out between some min and max?

Comment: they write [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints) about 3 types of parent widgets (*"Generally, there are three kinds of boxes, in terms of how they handle their constraints:"*)

Comment: i saw another your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417186/specific-min-and-max-size-for-expanded-widgets-in-column), does it mean you dont have `ConstrainedBox` anymore? what do you want to achieve actually? to layout your child widgets exactly as you want? if so, maybe use `Stack` or `CustomMultiChildLayout` widgets

Comment: @pskink actually, I want to build an accordion effect, i.e. where you swipe up and widgets get shrunk one by one, starting from the bottom. I have built something like that, but I am not happy that I need to specify all min/max extents and thought there should be a way to infer the extents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I figured out the following:

```
Widget build(BuildContext _) => Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 400),
              child: Container(color: Colors.yellow))));
```

will render the box at 50 pixel, and

```
Widget build(BuildContext _) => Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 400),
              child: Container(color: Colors.yellow))));
```

will render the box at 400 pixels.

So, it looks like IntrinsicHeight will size the child to its `minHeight`, whereas just putting it in a Container will yield `maxHeight`.

Comment: You can still use the container to let the child be as small as it wants to. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52415126/1502079