# Specific min and max size for expanded widgets in Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Column with a set of Expanded widgets.

Is there a way to control the range in which they expand? I want one widget to expand only to a certain size and make the rest available to other widgets.

EDIT:

Because I got two probably misleading answers, I’d like to clarify. I want something like this:

```
Expanded(flex: 1, minSize: 50, maxSize: 200, child: ...)
```

That means that this expanded widget takes a flex of 1, but should never be smaller than 50 and bigger than 200.

Comment: try using constrained box

Comment: @nick.tdr you mean I just put a ConstrainedBox inside of Expanded to control the min/max extents?

Comment: yes that's right. I posted the answer below.

Comment: @nick.tdr please see my edit...

Comment: yes I see that. But I don't see any option in expanded widget to do that. Expanded widgets only have have flex value to define the ratio of their size.

Comment: Constraint box with min and max height can allow its child to be in that range but Expanded widget cannot be a child of the Constraint box since its not a flex widget.

Comment: @nick.tdr i know, and that’s why I did ask at StackOverflow... so, how can it be done?

Comment: Flutter noob here. Wondering what's the recommended way to solve this kind of issue. Subclassing `Column` to give it more advanced layout behavior? Using `LayoutBuilder` and `SizedBox` and compute dimensions programmatically?

Comment: Where you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: @user3808307 I rolled my own layout widget

Answer (score 22):

In short: there is no simple answer without calculating the size.

First you need to know: `Widget with Size` dominates the available size in **Row/Column**, then **Flexible/Expanded** share the remaining space.

```
Column(
  children:[
    Flexible(...
    Expanded(...
    SizedBox(...  // <- dominates the available size first
  ]
)
```

And the parent widget dominates the size of the child widget:

```
Column(
  children:[
    Flexible(flex: 1),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: SizedBox(...  // size can't be larger than 1/2
  ]
)
```

It is the choice problem if the size exceeds or is insufficient. I can show some simple examples below:

(BTW: I replace **ConstrainedBox** with **SizedBox** because we only use `maxWidth/maxHeight`. check [Understanding constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints))

### Flex with max size

This case is simple and only needs **Flexible** + **SizedBox**:

```
Row(
  children: [
  Flexible(flex: 1, child: _textWidget('Flex:1')),
  Flexible(
    flex: 1,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 300,
      child: _textWidget('Flex: 1, max: 300'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

### Flex with min/max size

This case needs the total size (from **LayoutBuilder**) and the percentage of the widget size:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraint) {
    final maxWidth = constraint.maxWidth;
    
    return Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(flex: 1, child: _textWidget('Flex:1')),
        SizedBox(
          width: (maxWidth / 3).clamp(200, 300),
          child: _textWidget('Flex:1, min: 200, max: 300'),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: (maxWidth / 3).clamp(200, 300),
          child: _textWidget('Flex:1, min: 200, max: 300'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
)
```

### Code Example

https://dartpad.dev/?id=f098f9764acda1bcc58017aa0bc0ec09

[image]

Comment: really grateful for the clear explanation. Not manny folks seem to really know this.

Answer (score 9):

When using ConstrainedBox in Rows my minWidth is ignored and the maxWidth is used as a fixed size.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there's no elegant pre-built way in Flutter to do this.

The answer by @HugoPassos is only partially complete. A ConstrainedBox will not change its size unless its content changes size. I believe what you're looking for is for the box to be say 1 / 4 of the width of row if 1/4 of the row is greater than the min and higher than the max.

Here's a working main.dart that get's the job done with width in a row, though you could just as easily use height in a column:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Center(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              ConstrainedWidthFlexible(
                minWidth: 50,
                maxWidth: 200,
                flex: 1,
                flexSum: 4,
                outerConstraints: constraints,
                child: SizeLogger(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: Size.infinite.width,
                      height: Size.infinite.height,
                      child: Text('click me to log my width')),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: Container(color: Colors.green),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
            ],
          ));
        }));
  }
}

class SizeLogger extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  SizeLogger({required this.child});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => {print('context.size!.width ${context.size!.width}')},
        child: child);
  }
}

class ConstrainedWidthFlexible extends StatelessWidget {
  final double minWidth;
  final double maxWidth;
  final int flex;
  final int flexSum;
  final Widget child;
  final BoxConstraints outerConstraints;
  ConstrainedWidthFlexible(
      {required this.minWidth,
      required this.maxWidth,
      required this.flex,
      required this.flexSum,
      required this.outerConstraints,
      required this.child});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: minWidth,
        maxWidth: maxWidth,
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: _getWidth(outerConstraints.maxWidth),
        child: child,
      ),
    );

  }

  double _getWidth(double outerContainerWidth) {
    return outerContainerWidth * flex / flexSum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `ConstrainedBox`.

You can create a `List` of `Widget`s with both `ConstrainedBox` and `Expanded`, as following:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    ConstrainedBox(
      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: 50,
        maxWidth: 100,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.green),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: In this example, minWidth is unused. The red container is always 100 wide.

Comment: @BenjaminLee Indeed. [This is my problem except with height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343559/get-both-minheight-and-maxheight-boxconstraints-respected-when-resizing).

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! There is a way to control maxHeight and maxWidth inside a Row or Column (unbounded Widgets). You could use the Widget LimitedBox in which your maxHeight and maxWidth parameters only works inside unbounded Widgets.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LimitedBox-class.html

```
Column(
  children: [
    LimitedBox(
      maxHeight: 200,
      maxWidth: 200,
      child: Container(),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: But not min width and height in thsi answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Please, Check it out.

```
Expanded(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: Container(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 500),
        child: Container(
          child: DesiredWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Instead of directly expanding the desired widget, you should expand and align a container, then set the constrainedbox as a child of the container and then insert the desired widget as a child of the constrainedbox.
This way i managed to render the widget precisely as big as it needs to be, but never exceeding 500 height.

Answer (score -2):

You can use constraint box to use the range of min and max width like below:

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Text 1"),
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30, maxWidth: 40, minWidth: 30),
        ),
        Text("Text 2")
      ],
    )
```