# Allow Expanded Widget to take more space if needed

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the `Expanded` widget to have a minimum width (specified in `flex`) but it shall also increase its width if the child needs it.
However, it only interprets `flex` as some kind of fixed width.

You can see it in the following screenshot.

Example Code:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 117,
      child: Widget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 400,
      child: Widget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 13,
      child: Widget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 470,
      child: Widget(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @HazarBelge does work, however I found a more elegant solution:

Component:

```dart
class PercentageRow extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<double> percentages;
  final List<Widget> children;

  const PercentageRow({required this.percentages, required this.children});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      columnWidths: percentages.map((p) => IntrinsicColumnWidth(flex: p)).toList().asMap(),
      children: [TableRow(children: children)],
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
PercentageRow(
    percentages: [0.3, 0.7],
    children: [
      Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text('A LOOOOOONG TEXT')),
      Container(color: Colors.green),
    ],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use constraint property of Container Widget. -I think-

You can try this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 117,
      child: Container(
         constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 40),
         child: Widget(),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 400,
      child: Container(
         constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 40),
         child: Widget(),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 13,
      child: Container(
         constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 40),
         child: Widget(),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 470,
      child: Container(
         constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 40),
         child: Widget(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

**Edit 1:** I created custom widget called MinHeightExpanded.

MinHeightExpanded Widget:

```
class MinHeightExpanded extends StatefulWidget {
  const MinHeightExpanded({
    Key? key,
    required this.minHeight,
    required this.flex,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double minHeight;
  final int flex;
  final Color color;

  @override
  _MinHeightExpandedState createState() => _MinHeightExpandedState();
}

class _MinHeightExpandedState extends State<MinHeightExpanded> {
  bool setToMin = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) => setState(() {}));
    return !setToMin
        ? Expanded(
            flex: widget.flex,
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints boxConstraints) {
                print("${widget.color}: ${boxConstraints.maxHeight}");
                if (boxConstraints.maxHeight < widget.minHeight) {
                  setToMin = true;
                }
                return Container(
                  color: widget.color,
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            color: widget.color,
            height: widget.minHeight,
          );
  }
}
```

Use it like that:

```
     SizedBox(
        height: size.height,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            MinHeightExpanded(
              flex: 117,
              color: Colors.red,
              minHeight: 40,
            ),
            MinHeightExpanded(
              flex: 400,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              minHeight: 40,
            ),
            MinHeightExpanded(
              flex: 13,
              color: Colors.blue,
              minHeight: 400,
            ),
            MinHeightExpanded(
              flex: 470,
              color: Colors.green,
              minHeight: 40,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The `Expanded` widget seems to have higher priority.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417186/specific-min-and-max-size-for-expanded-widgets-in-column) can give you a hint. I didn't find a way for now, too.

Comment: I edited my answer. You may want to check out. It works so well.

Comment: I edited it to minWidth on my side. Thanks, it is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

If I underestand correctly, here is the answer to your question.

Use the Flexible widget instead of the Expanded.
[Flutter: Expanded vs Flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52645944/10580513)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the `Expanded` for the child you want increase the width. Like

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 117,
      child: Widget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 400,
      child: Widget(),
    ),
    Widget(),
    Expanded(
      flex: 470,
      child: Widget(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

if you do not want to set the percentage, you can use `IntrinsicWidth`, like

```
    IntrinsicWidth(
        child: Row(children: [
      Widget(),
      Widget(),
      Widget(),
      Widget(),
    ]));
```

BUT, it is expensive

Comment: Well, I don't know the percentages beforehand. It could also be the first item.

Comment: @TienDoNam I try another suggestion