# Flutter ConstrainedBox on TextFormField doesn't set height as expected

Tags: flutter

I'd like to set a min height on a TextFormField with multiline enabled and it should only expand when newline exceeds the current height. Once the maxHeight was reached, TextFormField automatically becomes scrollable by default. This is similar to what we see on apps with Messaging compose TextFields.

However, in my case the ConstrainedBox that wraps around it doesn't seem to set the minHeight I configured. Instead, the ConstrainedBox uses the maxHeight by default.

Any idea what I configured incorrectly?

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, height: 100),
      ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: 100,
          maxHeight: 300,
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          autofocus: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Write something'),

          /// Enable multiline
          expands: true,
          maxLines: null,

          /// Message character max length
          maxLength: 3000,
        ),
      ),
      Container(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, height: 100),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: Demo]

#### Minimal Repro

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, height: 100),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: 100,
                maxHeight: 300,
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                autofocus: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Write something'),

                /// Enable multiline
                expands: true,
                maxLines: null,

                /// Message character max length
                maxLength: 3000,
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, height: 100),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56422361/2497859). It looks like I need to wrap ConstrainedBox with an IntrinsicHeight widget. As mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html), IntrinsicHeight is used if a child widget can attempt to expand infinitely or size itself to a definite height.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, height: 100),
      /// wrap ConstrainedBox with IntrinsicHeight
      IntrinsicHeight(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: 100,
            maxHeight: 300,
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Write something'),

            /// Enable multiline
            expands: true,
            maxLines: null,

            /// Message character max length
            maxLength: 3000,
          ),
        ),
        Container(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, height: 100),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image: Demo]